# Помогите разобраться с Excel файлом

Tags: xml, макрос

Есть у меня Excel (xml) файл, который делал ранее анализ данных, а сейчас на последнем шаге перестал работать. Не могу понять, почему он перестал работать, может кто поможет даже за вознаграждение (если требуется)?

Файл прекрапил, а как должно правильно работать: Нажимаешь на вкладку "START" и жмешь на поиск, затем появляется список игр и там напротив каждого матча есть кнопка "Get match" и после этого он открывает тебе складку "analez". Сейчас не работает именно сама вкладка аналез, а до этого работала

Прошу помогите, **ПОЖАЛУЙСТА!**

Сам файл - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_pgitYG4lhelPNJrU7bSL28bAYcCcujB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: 1. Расширеие не xml, а .xlsb. 2. Называйте листы и кнопки так, как они именованы в файле. так легче ориентироваться. 3. Не работает что? Переход на лист  `analez`, что-то на этом листе?

Comment: Не работает анализ матчей после нажатия на кнопку "Get match". То есть что-то ссылается на внешние ресурсы видимо, нужно знать на какие